Proof Inequality Question: Lagrange Multiplier
Exercise: Given that the function
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(x,y,z\right)= xyz\
\mbox{subject to the}\ constraint\ x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} = 3$$ gives us $1$ as the maximum value,

showing that for any non-negative numbers $a,b\ \mbox{and}\ c$ we have
$$
\sqrt[3]{abc} \le \frac{a+b+c}{3}
$$
I knew that with the constraint and applying the Lagrange Multiplier gives us
$$
\operatorname{f}\left(x,y,z\right) = xyz\le 1
$$
I have tried many ways, but there is still a mess.

Could you help me to proof the question: That would help me improve my Math skills significantly.
My question is: Where is the appropriate point to continuously prove the question effectively ?.

The method of the Lagrange multipliers is effective in this case, although there are other ways

Can you provide what you have tried - say what you think is the best attempt?

I tried to let $a=x^2, b=y^2, and c=z^2$ to get $a+b+c = 3$ to verify the problem, but there is no guarantee that a+b+c =3. So, I failed. Second, I have tried to imagine that the constraint will be the first octant, so I started with $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge0$
